# Why is my android emulator home screen Blank?

Tags: android

I've been trying out some Android tutorials, and I have a problem with my emulator (I didn't used to have this problem):

When I hit the Home Button, it looks like this: [image]

Even after waiting for half an hour, nothing shows up. Does anyone know why is it that the Home screen is blank ?

Comment: what is your android target version?

Comment: @hovanessyan mine is version 2.2

Comment: OK, have you tried: changing target version(higher), creating new emulator?

Comment: @hovanessyan I have multiple emulators. The other emulators are working. But what is the reason that the Home screen is blank for this emulator?

Comment: I have no idea, it could be a bug. It could be that some code you've tested, tries to detect when the system is about to launch the Home Screen (e.g. simulate override of Home button).

Comment: @hovanessyan ok thanks. (it isn't my code btw, it's a new project which I haven't added any code)